# ImageView set image

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I use two ways to set image for imageView, by xml and by code `setBackgroundResource`

eg. `img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.task_learn_lock);`

OR xml

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/task_learn_lock"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

But the result is different, the image created by code is streched vertically.  Anyone know why?  I need to set a new image when the app is running. I tried to post a screen shot, but i do not have enough reputation to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is because the default *content* (defined by xml) of the `imageView`'s are different for these two approaches.

In your second method that sets the background image programmatically, I guess you should have set a default `drawable` image that is different from `@drawable/task_learn_lock` in *size* and *aspect ratio*.

Since the `layout_height` and `layout_width` of your `ImageView` are defined as `wrap_content`, the aspect ratio of your `ImageView` will be the same as your default `src` image. Therefore when you set the background image by `img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.task_learn_lock)`, the image will be stretched to fit the current `ImageView`'s dimension.

It appears in your case that you want to set the content to be `@drawable/task_learn_lock` but not the background of your ImageView, you should use `setImageResource` instead of `setBackgroundResource`.

Comment: I tried to add two images side by side with preset src, can show nicely, but it add the image using code, the image will show differently.

Comment: hi so are you suggesting me to fix the imageView width and height size?

Comment: It really depends on your situation, but in general this is not a good practice. A quick fix is to use a default image that matches the size of `R.drawable.task_learn_lock`

Comment: @kggoh BTW, it appears in your case that you want to set the *content* (`src`) to be `@drawable/task_learn_lock` but not the *background* of your `ImageView`, you should use `setImageResource` instead of `setBackgroundResource`

Comment: Yes. you are right. Now it works even i put size of wrap_content. Thanks.